# MVC Calendar values not saved to database after creating

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, calendar

**Create view**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <br />
        <label>Start Time</label>
        <br />
        <div class="dp">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datetimepicker6" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript for calendar**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var array = ["2015-12-25", "2015-12-24", "2015-12-31"]
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
                if (noWeekend[0]) {
                    return [array.indexOf(jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date)) == -1]
                } else {
                    return noWeekend;
                }
            }, minDate: 0
        });
        $(function () { $('#startDate').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends }); });

        $(function () {
            var date = new Date();
            var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
            var currentDate = date.getDate();
            var currentYear = date.getFullYear();
            $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker({
                minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate), daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
                disabledDates: [
                        moment("12/25/2015"),
                    moment("12/24/2015")
                ]
            });
            $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
                minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate), daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
                disabledDates: [
                        moment("12/25/2015"),
                    moment("12/24/2015")
                ]
            });

        });
    </script>
```

[image]

I have a create action where I can choose the startDate and EndDate using a calendar. But after I select the dates and create, the dates don't get saved in the database but other values in the same form do. Thus it doesn't appear in the table as well. How do I solve this?

Comment: How are you posting back the dates and saving them (the html you have shown is an input without a name attribute so wont post back a value)

Comment: @StephenMuecke oh i don't have that. I thought it will be automatic like normal textboxes :o so its something like that? var dt = $("#FromDateCollected").val();
alert(dt);

Comment: You need to give the input a `name` attribute that matches the property in your model. But its best to use the HtmlHelpers to generate the html - `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.yourProperty, new { @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Works now thank you :D Mind posting it so I can mark it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your manually generating the `<input>` element but not giving it a `name` attribute so its value is not posted back. The `name` attribute needs to match the name of your model property, and the best way to generate this is to use the strongly typed html helpers

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.yourPropertyName, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

which will generate an `id` attribute `id="yourPropertyName"` so that the script can refer to `$('#yourPropertyName').datetimepicker()`. Alternatively, you can give it a different `id` attribute using `new { @class = "form-control", id="datetimepicker6" }`